# SXA doesn't recognize font files - how do I include them in my theme?

Tags: sxa, experience-editor, content-editor

I have a pretty typical font setup: in my creative-exchange theme folder, I placed some custom font files and I reference my fonts like so:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Graphik";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("fonts/Graphik-Regular-Web.woff2") format('woff2');
}
```

However, when I go to Experience Editor, I see the browser is trying to fetch the font but is getting a 500 error.  I already have my theme setup via SXA-cli, so it should have uploaded the fonts. I also tried directly adding the fonts to the content editor, but that didn't help either.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post the details of the 500 error you are getting? And also are you using the SXA asset optimizer?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the fonts directory of your local theme just isn’t anywhere in the config to be watched or uploaded. So, open up the gulp/config.js and add 'fonts/**/*.*' to one of the sections:

[image]

Source :: https://citizensitecore.com/2021/08/11/custom-fonts-not-uploading-to-sxa-theme/